# Add a # to every line in a file with certain string with sed

Tags: bash, search, replace, sed

I have a file looking like this (just a part of it)

```
    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm      fwhm                                                
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.                                                
  7372.827 0.3524984 -9.457E-4  0.002683 -0.011192   0.07938        0.                                                
  7384.392 0.3463771 -0.001513  0.004369 -0.024297   0.05851        0.                                                
  7384.655 0.3457934 -0.003066  0.008867 -0.037102   0.07763        0.                                                
  7387.274  0.347539 -0.014332   0.04124 -0.136604   0.09856        0.                                                
    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm                                                
  7391.392 0.3548613 -0.044781    0.1262 -0.203154    0.2071        0.                                                
  7391.645 0.3539104 -0.008767   0.02477 -0.021864    0.3767        0.                                                
    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm                                                
  7400.522 0.3491196 -4.204E-4  0.001204 -0.005909   0.06684        0.                                                
  7405.889  0.348969 -6.845E-4  0.001961 -0.009793   0.06566        0.
```

I want to add a `#` in the beginning of each line containing the strings `center`, `cont`, etc. They all look similar, so a search for `center` should be sufficient.

If in addition I could add to the script, that nothing will happen, if they line already contains a `#` that would be great, but not super important here.

The output should look like this:

```
   #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm      fwhm                                                
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.                                                
  7372.827 0.3524984 -9.457E-4  0.002683 -0.011192   0.07938        0.                                                
  7384.392 0.3463771 -0.001513  0.004369 -0.024297   0.05851        0.                                                
  7384.655 0.3457934 -0.003066  0.008867 -0.037102   0.07763        0.                                                
  7387.274  0.347539 -0.014332   0.04124 -0.136604   0.09856        0.                                                
   #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm                                                
  7391.392 0.3548613 -0.044781    0.1262 -0.203154    0.2071        0.                                                
  7391.645 0.3539104 -0.008767   0.02477 -0.021864    0.3767        0.                                                
   #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm                                                
  7400.522 0.3491196 -4.204E-4  0.001204 -0.005909   0.06684        0.                                                
  7405.889  0.348969 -6.845E-4  0.001961 -0.009793   0.06566        0.
```

I think `sed` could solve this problem, but if anyone has a better idea I would like to here it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with sed:

```
 sed -i.bak '/center/s/^\([^#]\)/#\1/' file.txt
```

What is happening (from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm), [man sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) and [sed regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)):

```
-i.bak     Edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
/center/   Matches lines that contain the word center.
s/???/???/ Or s/regexp/replacement/, Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.
/          Field separator to 's'.
^          Match first character on line.
\(         Start back reference.
[^#]       Do not match any charcter (^ = don't) in this list (only # listed).
\)         End back reference.
#          Literal '#'
\1         The first back reference.
```

Same thing only do not produce a backup file (file.txt.bak):

```
 sed -i '/center/s/^\([^#]\)/#\1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`, you could say:

```
sed -r 's/^(\s+)(center)/\1#\2/g' filename
```

This would result into:

```
    #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm      fwhm          
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.           
  7372.827 0.3524984 -9.457E-4  0.002683 -0.011192   0.07938        0.           
  7384.392 0.3463771 -0.001513  0.004369 -0.024297   0.05851        0.           
  7384.655 0.3457934 -0.003066  0.008867 -0.037102   0.07763        0.           
  7387.274  0.347539 -0.014332   0.04124 -0.136604   0.09856        0.           
    #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm          
  7391.392 0.3548613 -0.044781    0.1262 -0.203154    0.2071        0.           
  7391.645 0.3539104 -0.008767   0.02477 -0.021864    0.3767        0.           
    #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm          
  7400.522 0.3491196 -4.204E-4  0.001204 -0.005909   0.06684        0.           
  7405.889  0.348969 -6.845E-4  0.001961 -0.009793   0.06566        0.
```

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can filter lines with `center` with `/center/` and then on those replace the beginning of line (`^`) with `#`:

```
$ sed '/center/s/^/#/' file
#    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm      fwhm
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.
  7372.827 0.3524984 -9.457E-4  0.002683 -0.011192   0.07938        0.
  7384.392 0.3463771 -0.001513  0.004369 -0.024297   0.05851        0.
  7384.655 0.3457934 -0.003066  0.008867 -0.037102   0.07763        0.
  7387.274  0.347539 -0.014332   0.04124 -0.136604   0.09856        0.
#    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm
  7391.392 0.3548613 -0.044781    0.1262 -0.203154    0.2071        0.
  7391.645 0.3539104 -0.008767   0.02477 -0.021864    0.3767        0.
#    center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm     lfwhm
  7400.522 0.3491196 -4.204E-4  0.001204 -0.005909   0.06684        0.
  7405.889  0.348969 -6.845E-4  0.001961 -0.009793   0.06566        0.
```

And if you need the `#` to be exactly next to `center` text, then this makes it: catch the spaces and then print them back before the `#`.

```
$ sed -r '/center/s/^(\s*)/\1#/' file
    #center      cont      flux       eqw      core     gfwhm      fwhm
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.
...
```

If you do not have the `-r` option in your `sed` you can use the equivalent:

```
sed '/center/s/^\(\s*\)/\1#/' file
```

With `awk` it is even faster: you can filter lines containing `center` and add `#` to the first field:

```
$ awk '/center/ {$1="#"$1}1' file
#center cont flux eqw core gfwhm fwhm
  7367.332 0.3494628 -0.002165  0.006196 -0.026459   0.07688        0.
  7372.827 0.3524984 -9.457E-4  0.002683 -0.011192   0.07938        0.
...
```

Comment: Speed is not a concern here, but thanks for the very nice examples and explanation. It works just fine, but as it is now, cforbish's method is the best.

Comment: No problem :) I don't see many differences between both, apart from the fact he is using `-i` to in place edition.

Comment: last "g" is ot needed in this case (only 1 substitution)

Comment: Errr you are right, @NeronLeVelu, updated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/center/,"#&")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "/center/ !b;s/^\s*/&#/"
```

and in this case we also could try

```
sed "/[0-9]/ b;s/^\s*/&#/"
```

assumling there is no digit in text line or

```
sed "/[a-zA-Z]/ s/^\s*/&#/"
```

assuming there is not letter in data lines